# Passing the configuration variable on teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have a Job A and Job B in teamcity, Job B is a dependency for Job A(continuous build and deployment job). I use/pick the parameters channels, environment and branch in both the jobs during the build trigger. So when I trigger the build for Job A I select these parameters but these values are not been pickedup in Job B.

Can some one please help me on how to pass these parameters into the dependency jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dep.<btID>.<property name>` format to get the property from the dependent build (see [Dependencies Properties](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties) for details).

So in case job A depends on job B and job B has id `jobB`, you might use `%dep.jobB.paramaterName%` reference to get `parameterName` parameter from job B.

**Update**

Since TeamCity 9.0 there is a possibility to redefine parameters in dependency builds. You should use `reverse.dep.<btID>.<property name>` format, as described [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties)

E.g.: if job `A` has parameter called `reverse.dep.jobB.param` (defined either as build configuration parameters or in the custom build dialog), job `B` can use it as param called `param`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I see what you are saying but the problem is I wanted to use the Job A parameter in Job B.

I want to use the parent parameter in the dependency job.

Comment: ok, I see, so you should use `%reverse.dep.<btID>.<property name>%`, as described [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-DependenciesProperties)

Comment: When  ever i use %reverse.dep.<btID>.<property name>% into my build configuration(Job B) its asking me to define "reverse.dep.<btID>.<property name>" in the parameters(please see the attachment).

Comment: Cannot see the attachment, and, by the way, what is your version of TeamCity?

Comment: Teamcity 9.1.3 enterprise is the version

Comment: Seems I've figured it out: you're trying to get parameter of the main (dependent) build in the dependency, but it is impossible (one of the main reasons for that is that main build haven't been started yet and its parameters haven't been calculated). However, it is possible to pass parameter(s) to the dependency using `reverse.dep...` parameters (defined either as build configuration parameters or in the custom build dialog)

Comment: yeah, I understand. Thanks @cyberskunk

Answer (score 0):

I use an initializing job (we'll call it Job C) that becomes a dependency for the other builds. It doesn't do much besides set common parameters for the downstream builds. Job B and Job A both have Job C as a dependency, in addition to the dependency of Job A on Job B. This also lets you cascade the same branch through several different downstream build configurations and keep Job A and Job B on the same build number (using %dep.x.build.number% as cyberskunk described) if you so desire.

The downside is you will have to trigger the build from Job C if you want any custom parameters to trickle through. It's not a problem for my use case.